# Express how to send html file with json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I need to send html file (frontend is on ReactJS) with a json that contains some user info **from request**.

I try this, but this give me a `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error

```
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {

res.json({ message: req.*something* });
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"), (e) => {

     if (e) {
         console.log(`\nEROR\n${e}\nEROR\n`);
         res.send(`<h1 style='text-align:center'>ERROR ${e.status}</h1>`);
     }
 });
});
```

I try to search how to do this, but get solutions only for "js views"

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to send the file, or render it's content on the page?. And also once you can not use `.json()` and then `sendFile()`, because once the server sends back the headers, he can't be sending another package of new headers with new content etc...

Comment: @AdnaneAr i want to render page, reactJS dinamicly renders content, there only one index.html

Comment: Then why not render the index.html on react and use express as an AJAX end point, you could do an HTTP GET request to fetch the json data from that end point.

Comment: @AdnaneAr becose that json contains information from request

Comment: You could send the informations through headers, post fields or get queries. And when you receive them on the server-side you can trait them and render the result as json. And then on the client-side(React) you can make a component that does an AJAX request to that API end point that we've jute created using express and fetch the data... and VOILA, you can do whatever you want with the data on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP request can only have one HTTP response. An HTTP response can only have one body.

If I type `http://example.com/` into my browser's address bar, then I get an HTML document back.

My browser wouldn't know what to do if it sent back an HTML document **and** a JSON text but you're trying to send back a JSON text (`res.json`) **and** an HTML document (`res.sendFile`) **and** a fragment of HTML (`res.send`)!

---

You could send back a JSON text where a property on an object was a string containing an HTML document.

```
{ "html": "<!DOCTYPE ... etc", somethingElse: 123 }
```

You could send back an HTML document with JSON in the body.

You could send back an HTML document with a link to a different URL that returns JSON.

---

> i want to render page, reactJS dinamicly renders content, there only one index.html

General, the approach to take here would be to:

1. Create a directory to contain the output of building your React project
2. Use `express.static` to serve that directory from the root
3. Create an Express router to handle providing any JSON that needs to be dynamically generated
4. Mount that at a path like `/api/`
5. Use Ajax to make HTTP requests to the API from the React application

So your server-side could would end up looking something like:

```
const myApiRouter = require('./routers/api');

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use("/api", myApiRouter);
app.use(express.static('path/to/react/build'));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

And then a React component would do something like:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/foo')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setApiData(data));
    }, []);

    if (!apiData) return <Loading />;

    return <ul>
        { apiData.map(item => <li>{item}</li>) }
    </ul>
};
```

---

> i need to send to send requested url back, for routing on frontend site (react-router-dom), if i just type localhost:8000/main, it will throw "cannot get /main" insted of /main rout on frontend, so i send request back and change route on frontend

Generally, unless you are doing SSR or static page generation, I would suggest not using BrowserRouter. Having a bunch of different URLs serve up the same content which just bootstraps different bits of client-side code isn't create for caching.

I would use HashRouter instead.

If you really want to use Browser Router, then the structure of the Express app would be similar, you just need to default to serving up the index file for anything that would otherwise 404.

```
app.use("/api", myApiRouter);
app.use(express.static('path/to/react/build'));
app.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile("path/to/react/build/index.html"));
```

That said, static page generation and SRR are *excellent* things to do and I heartily recommend them. I generally use Next.js to achieve these. (And it has its own routing system so you'd be ditching React Router entirely for this).

If you use [Static Generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-recommended) then the resulting static files can be served up as per the first Express.js example at the top of this answer.

If you use [SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) then you'll use the Next.js server instead of Express.

Comment: @даниил дуров There you go, that's what I was explainning you in the comments section. Here this gentle guy made you a complete example and explanations.

Answer (score -1):

Because when you call res.sendFile() it send index.html to client. You cannot use res.send() in callback. Why would you do that?

Comment: i need to send to send requested url back, for routing on frontend site (react-router-dom), if i just type   localhost:8000/main, it will throw "cannot get /main" insted of /main rout on frontend, so i send request back and change route on frontend